Why is $g = \partial_1 u − i\partial_2u$ analytic?

The construction of the conjugate harmonic function $v$ of $u$ involves
integration, similarly the following consideration.
If a harmonic function $u$ is given in $D$ and one defines
$g : D\to \mathbb{C}$ by $g = \partial_1 u − i\partial_2u$ ,
then $g$ is analytic.

Can someone help me understanding this statement? Why is $\partial_{12}u =\partial_{21}u?$

Suppose $f$ is de.fined in an open set $E \in \mathbb{ R}^2$
, suppose that $\partial_1 f, 
\partial_{21}f/, and \partial_2 f$ exist at every point of $E$, and $\partial_{21}f$ is continuous at some point
$(a, b) \in E $ Then $\partial_{21}f(a,b)=\partial_{12}f(a,b)$.

However I wasn't able to prove that any harmonic function would satisfy this condition. I am still in the beginning of the complex analysis course and reading Complex analysis by Freitag and Busam, Also Cauchy Riemann differential equations are not enough to prove that $g$ is analytic, so How one should prove that $g$ is analytic?
I begin to think this book is not a "gentle" introduction to the subject, are my questions reasonable or imply that this book is too advanced for me?

You should know from your multivariable calculus class that for a “nice” ($C^2$) function, mixed partial derivatives are equal.

@TedShifrin It has been 2 years since I took multivariable calculus and I forgot almost every thing, but anyway I don't think we took anything rigorous in that course.

Should I relearn multivariable calculus?What books do you recommend me for it?

Well, I'm fond of my own text (and you can always look at some of the 112 YouTube lectures at your convenience), but I'm not sure you need to panic completely. You definitely will need to be comfortable with line integrals and Green's Theorem, the chain rule, etc. But for this particular question, what is the book's definition of a harmonic function? (My recollection, however, is that Freitag's is a graduate-level text, so maybe it may turn out to be a bit ambitious. Have you taken a real analysis course?)

@TedShifrin I only took single variable real analysis, also I don't remember line integrals and Green's Theorem.

@TedShifrin This book is a grad level !? What complex analysis book should I use?

You're going to need to know multivariable calculus, regardless of the book you use. You need to give more about your math background and motivation for your studies before I can begin to answer you.

@TedShifrin Linear algebra calculus (although I forgot calc 3), real analysis

You haven't told me your goals or reasons for learning complex analysis. Regardless, you will definitely need to solidify your multivariable calculus. Perhaps a book like Churchill and Brown (which is a bit more oriented toward applications) would be a better place to start.

@TedShifrin I need to it for college, I am self studying it because our education isn't good so I need to study it myself, I want a book that is less oriented toward applications.

The book you selected seems to have a good portion of it devoted to analytic number theory topics. I really do not know the book, so I cannot comment further.
